# Discord bot doesn't create a channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I have written a discord bot which should create a voice channel and move me to the channel created. No channel is created for my code and I wanted to ask how I can fix it. If possible, I will also gladly accept suggestions for moving players. Here is my code:

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Login successful")
        print("launching on version " + discord.__version__)


    async def create(self, ctx, message, guild):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return
        if message.content.startswith("!create"):
            server = ctx.message.server
            channelname = "test-channel"
            await discord.create_channel(server, channelname, type=discord.ChannelType.voice)
            print("Channel " + channelname + "created!")


client = MyClient()
client.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: How are you invoking `MyClient.create()`?

Comment: sorry , I am new and do not know what you mean

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: When do you expect the `create` code to run?  It almost looks like an `on_message` event, except for the extra arguments

Comment: a voice channel is to be created when "create" is written to a channel

Answer (score 0):

[discord.py](/questions/tagged/discord.py) uses a [system of events](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#event-reference) to determine what code to execute.  If you want your code to run, you need to associate it with an  event. You probably want to use the `message` event by writing an `on_message` method for your class.  The framework determines which callback to execute based on the name of the method, so the `on_message` method is run whenever the `message` event triggers:

```
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Login successful")
        print("launching on version " + discord.__version__)


    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return
        if message.content.startswith("!create"):
            server = ctx.message.server
            channelname = "test-channel"
            await server.create_voice_channel(channelname)
            print("Channel " + channelname + "created!")
```